# Will Ubuntu Pro provide support for network and Postgres problems?

Tags: support

I have two **problems with a home Ubuntu 20.04 workstation** and I'm **thinking about getting a commercial support plan**. I would love to hear anyone's experience using Canonical's offering (like Ubuntu Pro + support) vs any 3rd party support plan.

Here's two examples of things that I would rather pay for right now than continuing with my experimentation based on internet documentation and tutorials. Or just backing up important files and reinstalling.

1. I recently developed intermittent network instability when using any chromium-based browser. For example "Your connection was interrupted. A network change was detected.ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED". Those messages resolve themselves after ~ 2 seconds, with the desired page refreshing. Or browser-based file downloads that fail. Neither the "connection was interrupted" message or failed downloads occur on any other computer on my home network or on the Ubuntu workstation when using Firefox.
2. I can't remember how to set Postgres up for non-localhost access and would really just prefer to have somebody walk me though the necessary changes to postgresql.conf and pg_hba.conf (or possibly user permissions or firewall setting)

If I buy a Ubuntu Pro subscription, will someone from Canonical walk me through the solution of these issues? I am unsure if they might fall outside the scope of their support plans.

Comment: I agree with @ArturMeinild, under https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask I see this as a question "*no actual problem to be solved*" and seeking *opinions* which are better suited to Forums such as https://ubuntuforums.org/ rather than a Q&A site such as this one.

Comment: Also, if you opt for commercial Ubuntu Pro plan, I am not sure if Canonical will help you solve these network issues. I feel like Ubuntu Pro gives you security updates for universe packages, and extented support beyond the normal lifetime of a release.

Comment: I have edited the question to make it non opinion-based.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi I appreciate your edits. I did want to address whether there are other support plans I could consider.

Comment: In short, no. You're better off finding someone local who can provide technical support. Or asking specific technical questions here, and having people help you debug them.

Comment: If you have more specific question regarding support, you can contact Canonical https://ubuntu.com/support/contact-us

Comment: I just buckled down and at lest resolved my Postgres remote access issue.

Comment: And submitted the chromium problems to https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2486800&p=14142599#post14142599

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about features of Ubuntu Pro, and best addressed to the Ubuntu Pro sales team directly.

Comment: If you solved the problem on your own, then consider writing an answer, as it will help future users